# Select at least one of the checkbox in a form using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Good day.

Please I'm trying to use jquery to validate all checkboxes (i.e ensure that at least one checkbox is checked) in a form.
Moreso, I don't want the name of the radio which is "drink[]" to appear in the jquery code in the sense that I'm fetching some details from the database using PHP MySQL and I may not necessarily know the exact name for the radio button.

Here is my jquery code sample.

```
$("#go").click(function()
{
  $(#respondent_form input:checkbox").each(function()
  {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");

    if($("input:checkbox[name="+name+"]:checked").length == 0)
    {   
        $(this).focus();
       alert("Fill all fields");
       return false;
    }
 });
});
```

The html code sample goes thus:

```
<form id="respondent_form" action="" method="">
   <input type="checkbox" name="drink[]" value="Milo"/> Milo
   <input type="checkbox" name="drink[]" value="Tea"/> Tea
   <input type="checkbox" name="drink[]" value="Cowbell"/> Cowbell

   <button type="button" id="go"> Go </button>
 </form>
```

I'll be glad if this is resolved.
Thanks.

Comment: I dont want to write out the solution for you but think about th logic! You need to create a temorary varable .. e.g. var optionChoosed= false; then loop trough the objects... when one is selected set optionChoosed to true ... after the loop you can check te optionChoosed variable.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the loop:

```
$("#go").click(function() {
   if ($("#respondent_form input:checked").length == 0) {   
      alert("Fill all fields");
      return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm why is this working? since which jQuery version?

Comment: This is supported in all versions of jQuery. `input:checked` finds the `input` elements which have their `checked` property set. It does not matter if you have other `input` types in your form: they don't have that property set, so they are not selected.

Comment: @MichaelBotistouta, I saw your edit request, but that should have been a comment, not an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Hello;

use this code :

```
$('#respondent_form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var checkboxes = $('input[type="Checkbox"]');
    var checked = false;
    $.each(checkboxes, function(index,value){
        if ($(value).is(':checked')){
            checked = true;
        }
    }
    if (checked == false){
         alert("please complete all fields .");
    } else {
         $('#respondent_form').submit();
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution sir.
But I don't want the radio button name "drink[]" to appear in the jquery code because I'm fetching those details from the MySQL database via PHP.

The radio button name "drink[]" as used above is just an example.

Comment: The PHP code looks like this

<?php

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *FROM data");
$rows =mysqli_num_rows($query);

for($k=1;$k<=$rows;$k++)
{
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$id=$fetch[’id'];
echo "<input type=’checkbox' name=’$id[]’/>";
}

?>

Now how can I check if at least one of the checkboxes generated from the PHP MySQL code above is checked using jQuery, since you may not necessarily know the exact value of $id?

Thanks.

Comment: Change the name=drink[] to type=checkbox